# Conditional SUM not allowing operands

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get a `SUM` of `Order` `amount`s converted to a fixed currency. The `amount`s in `Order` table can be of different currencies.

If the `IsBase` flag in `Currency` table is `1`, then I want to divide with the `Rate`, else I want to multiply with the `Rate`.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN c.isBase = 1
            THEN SUM(o.Amount / c.Rate) 
            ELSE SUM(o.Amount * c.Rate)
            END
FROM   Orders o JOIN Currency c 
ON     o.Currency = c.Currency
```

This does not work and gives error:

> Column c.isBase' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

But the said column is not part of `SELECT`. It is part of a condition in `SELECT`. How can I make it work if I want to have the `SUM` like this?

Comment: You have to either place `isBase` in the `GROUP BY` clause, or place the `CASE` expression *inside* `SUM` function. It depends on your actual requirements.

Comment: Try using "GROUP BY c.isBase" at the end.

Comment: @Giorgos - Yes it works when I put CASE in Group By clause. Thanks!

Comment: @FuzzyTree - GROUP BY is not always needed for SUM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN c.isBase = 1
                THEN o.Amount / c.Rate
                ELSE o.Amount * c.Rate
                END) AS answer
    FROM   Orders o JOIN Currency c 
    ON     o.Currency = c.Currency
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put your `CASE` expression inside the `SUM` aggregate function:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.isBase = 1 THEN o.Amount / c.Rate ELSE o.Amount * c.Rate END) 
FROM Orders o
JOIN Currency c 
    ON  o.Currency = c.Currency
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```
SELECT CASE WHEN c.isBase = 1
            THEN SUM(o.Amount / c.Rate) 
            ELSE SUM(o.Amount * c.Rate)
            END
FROM   Orders o JOIN Currency c 
ON     o.Currency = c.Currency
GROUP BY c.isBase
```